# How can I explicitly set the Kernel using debian live-build?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

I'm using debian live-build to create my own kali linux live boot image. The image uses a chroot hook to install another kernel that I want to use (t2 linux kernel https://wiki.t2linux.org/). However, grub doesn't seem to use this kernel by default.

It seems the BIOS syslinux bootloader will use the correct kernel, but the grub EFI bootloader will not, unless I manually edit the configuration at startup. I know this because my VM used the correct kernel (confirmed with `uname -r`), and my actual hardware did not (except by manually editing the grub config at startup). I also noticed that these menus were slightly different (i.e. BIOS vs EFI). I've tried finding where the grub configuration is set with debian live-build (`live-build/config/bootloaders/grub/grub.cfg`), however, it seems they are just using environment variables or something (i.e. `@LINUX_LIVE@` is used for the kernel).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information, please let me know.